# How do I attach a few cubes via script. Blender 2.79. Pic =>

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, edit-mode, vertices

How to attach a lot of cubes to the **nearest vertices** of a certain object using a script?
I want to attach red cubes to the nearest **vertices** of yellow objects using a script.
Suppose red cubes belong to the group "GroupA". And these cubes need to be attached to the nearest vertices of the yellow object

I need your help.Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is your meaning of "attach"?  as parent? as join?

Comment: Cubes must follow the vertices as join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wLbJsnWiIbR8l2kdOFm8FgcCx-_mR0WY/view?usp=sharing) the blend file and test the script **(updated)**

in order to parent the cubes
[image: after]
[image: before]

```
import bpy


def conectando(vertice, objeto):
    cd = main.data
    cd.vertices[vertice].select=True
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.context.scene.objects[objeto].select_set(state=True) 
    bpy.ops.object.vertex_parent_set()
    bpy.context.scene.objects[objeto].select_set(state=False) 
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    cd.vertices[vertice].select=False



print("*"*50)


#get active object
main = bpy.context.active_object
mat = main.matrix_world

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

vertices = [v for v in main.data.vertices]

conectar=[]
for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if ob.type == 'MESH' and not ob.name == main.name:
        # select object in order to join at the end
        #ob.select_set(state=True) # select object in order to join at the end
        distance = []
        for c in vertices:
            v = c.co
            loc = mat @ v #matrix world of vertex co
            distance.append([(loc-ob.location).length, c.index, ob.name])

        distance.sort()
        conectar.append(distance[0])


for c in conectar:
    conectando(c[1],c[2])
```

---

[image: original meshes]
[image: after script]

```
import bpy

print("*"*50)


#get active object
main = bpy.context.active_object
main_coords = [(main.matrix_world @ v.co) for v in main.data.vertices]

#move other mesh objects to nearest location in active object
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    if ob.type == 'MESH' and not ob.name == main.name:
        ob.select_set(state=True) # select object in order to join at the end
        distance = []
        for c in main_coords:            
            distance.append([(c-ob.location).length, c])



        distance.sort()   
        ob.location = distance[0][1]    
        print(distance[0][1])
            #$print(ob.name + str(tuple(ob.location)))

#join all objects
bpy.ops.object.join()
```

Comment: Maybe `ob.matrix_world.translation` since `ob.location` is a local coord in relation to its parent. Would also loop thru `context.scene.objects` rather than all objects in file to avoid complications of using objects  unlinked or linked to other scene.

Comment: Okay thank you. And how to make them follow without combining into one object. I need a function like "vertex_parent_set". Sorry i was wrong yesterday :(

Comment: @RenBenPBR test new script

Comment: @yhoyo I try to run on version 2.79 and the console points to line 37, `in <module>  Type Error: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'Matrix' and 'Vector' ` https://imgur.com/a/daAKxqE

Comment: @RenBenPBR test in 2.8

Comment: @yhoyo yea, it's working in 2.8, thanks you!
I'm upset that it does not work on the old version :(